# WordPress: JS is loaded but functions in it are not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a js file named "main.js" and I enqueued it using wp_enqueue_script in function.php file. This file is getting loaded in my page-{slug}.php, but the functions in it are not executing at all.

The function.php file:

```
function df_enqueue_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'main-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/src/library/js/main.js', array(), '1.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/src/library/js/bootstrap.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '5.6', true );

}

// Register the df_enqueue_scripts with wp_enqueue_scripts hook.
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'df_enqueue_scripts' );
```

page-{slug}.php file:

```
<?php

get_header();
?>

<button type="button" id="ad-button">Ad</button>
<button type="button" id="mm-button">MM</button>
<button type="button" id="photo-button">Photography</button>
<div id="display-photo"></div>
<div id="display-mm"></div>
<div id="display-ad"></div>

<?php

get_footer();
```

main.js file:

```
$( '#photo-button' ).on( 'click',
function () {
    $( '#display-photo' ).html("Hello <b>world!</b>");
}
);
```

In short, I write anything in main.js file, the changes which I expect doesn't happen or doesn't reflect in my page-{slug}.php file.

Comment: Does the element `#photo-button` exist at the point this code runs? Have you tried wrapping the code into jQuery’s document.ready handler, and checked if that changes anything?

Comment: Everything @CBroe mentioned, also have your checked your browser Javascript Console to debug possible errors/warnings?

Comment: @CBroe Yes, #photo-button does exist. and also tried wrapping the code into jQuery’s document.ready handler. But nothing worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, the problem with **jQuery** wrong usage.
Probably, wrapping the function with **jQuery** allows using **$** variable
and could solve the problem

```
jQuery(function($){
        $( '#photo-button' ).on( 'click',
            function () {
                $( '#display-photo' ).html("Hello <b>world!</b>");
            }
        );
    })
```

The second required thing is to set **jQuery** as a dependency for
your script and to update the script version to **1.1**.

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'main-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/src/library/js/main.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.1', true );
```

Comment: I changed the version from 1.0 to 1.1 and it worked. Thanks for the solution. I am happy that the error got solved but I didn't understand why 1.0 version didn't worked and 1.1 worked

Comment: It's related to browser caching. When you change the script version - the browser refreshes the script cache. WordPress adds ver GET parameter to script URL. And after changing your script you should increase your script version. F.e 1.1 1.2. 2.0 etc...

Comment: oh...I got it. It was the cache problem. So for every single change in my js script, I also need to change the script's version number.